What is the historical justification for the 'per 100 gram of tissue' term in the units of cerebral blood volume?
The title of this post pretty much says it all. I've looked around quite a bit for the original paper that invoked the decision to normalize a fluid volume to $\frac{1}{100 \text{ gram}}$. I thought that some early infrared spectrophotometry studies (which I believe are the first quantifications of CBV) would explain this...but they do not. Perhaps this is related to a more general (and older) approach to perfusion quantification methods, but I really do not know.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about the history of science, and should be translated to the eponymous SE site.

The below is speculative, but I believe it to be approximately, if not entirely, correct.
The origin of this 'unit of reporting' appears to stem from the original attempts of Kety & Schmidt to provide the first quantitative measurement of cerebral blood flow (CBF). There are a few papers spanning several years...with the first one coming out in 1945...but the most relevant one that provides some insight is here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC439518/.
They provide a logical derivation that uses some basic calculus and laws of incompressible fluid flow to produce the following equation:
$$\text{CBF}(\tau)=\frac{\frac{Q_B(\tau)}{W}}{\int_0^{\tau}\left[A(t)-V(t)\right]dt}$$
, where $Q_B(\tau)$ denotes the number of N2O atoms in the brain (we will use the SI unit $\text{mol}$ to report this value), $W$ denotes the whole weight of the brain, and $A$ and $V$ represent the arterial and venous concentrations of N2O, respectively. The authors' derivation to this point in the paper is well explained, and the corresponding physical dimensions of CBF are easily tracked as being: $\displaystyle \frac{\text{volume}}{\text{time}\cdot\text{mass}}$.  If we choose centimeters cubed ($\text{cc}$) as our unit of volume, minutes ($\text{min}$) as our unit of time, and grams ($\text{g}$) as our unit of mass, then the dimension are more specifically written as: $\displaystyle \frac{\text{cc}}{\text{min}\cdot\text{g}}$. So far, so good...but where does the $\frac{1}{\text{100 g}}$ come from?
Their derivation continues with the following claim:

For long enough $\tau^*$, $\frac{Q_B(\tau^*)}{W}=V_{\tau^*}S$, where $S$ is the partitioning coefficient of N2O between the brain tissue and brain vasculature.

With no additional explanation, they then write:

By substituting appropriately and multiplying through by 100, one obtains a value for cerebral blood flow in convenient units: \begin{align} \text{CBF}(\tau^*)=\frac{100 V_{\tau^*}S}{\int_0^{\tau^*}[A(t)-V(t)]dt}\end{align} where CBF is expressed as cc. of blood flow per $100$ g. of brain per minute

These final steps are missing quite a bit of explanation...so here is my attempt at justifying the steps. Firstly, returning to the claim that:
$$\frac{Q_B(\tau^*)}{W}=V_{\tau^*}S \quad (\dagger_1)$$, you should immediately see that the physical dimensions do not match up (and therefore, the equality is invalid). On the left side we have $\displaystyle\frac{\text{mol}}{\text{g}}$, and on the right side, we have $\displaystyle\frac{\text{mol}}{\text{cc}}$. Importantly, though, we can write out these units a tad more informatively:

$\displaystyle\frac{\text{mol of N2O in brain tissue}}{\text{g of brain tissue}}$

$\displaystyle\frac{\text{mol of N2O in brain vasculature}}{\text{cc of brain vasculature}}$


Next, note that $S$, by definition, has units that can be represented as:
$$\frac{\frac{ \text{mol of N2O in brain tissue}}{ \text{cc brain tissue}}}{\frac{ \text{mol of N2O in brain vasculature}}{ \text{cc of brain vasculature}}}$$
Now, returning to $(\dagger_1)$, if we write out our more descriptive units we have:
\begin{align}\frac{Q_B(\tau^*)}{W}\frac{ \text{mol of N2O in brain tissue}}{ \text{g brain tissue}}&=V_{\tau^*}S \frac{\text{mol of N2O in brain vasculature}}{\text{cc of brain vasculature}} \cdot \frac{\frac{ \text{mol of N2O in brain tissue}}{ \text{cc brain tissue}}}{\frac{ \text{mol of N2O in brain vasculature}}{ \text{cc of brain vasculature}}}\\&=V_{\tau^*}S\frac{ \text{mol of N2O in brain tissue}}{ \text{cc brain tissue}}\end{align}
Notice that we still have this issue of physical dimension mismatch...however, if we approximate the density of the brain tissue as being largely similarly to water, then we know that water has the density of $~1.0 \frac{\text{g}}{\text{cc}}$...so we assert:
$$\text{density of brain tissue is approximately } 1.0 \frac{\text{g of brain tissue}}{\text{cc of brain tissue}}$$
Accordingly, if we multiply $V_{\tau^*}S\frac{ \text{mol of N2O in brain tissue}}{ \text{cc brain tissue}}$ by the inverse of the brain density, we have:
$$V_{\tau^*}S\cdot 1\frac{ \text{mol of N2O in brain tissue}}{ \text{cc brain tissue}} \cdot \frac{\text{cc of brain tissue}}{\text{g of brain tissue}}=V_{\tau^*}S \frac{\text{mol of N2O in brain tissue}}{\text{g of brain tissue}}$$
Therefore, the more correct way of writing $(\dagger_1)$ is:
$\frac{Q_B(\tau^*)}{W}=V_{\tau^*}S \cdot \rho^{-1}_{\text{brain}} \quad \color{green}{(\dagger_2)}$
At this point, if we substitute the $\color{green}{(\dagger_2)}$ expression in for the CBF formula, we have:
$$\text{CBF}(\tau^*)=\frac{V_{\tau^*}S \cdot \rho^{-1}_{\text{brain}}}{\int_0^{\tau}\left[A(t)-V(t)\right]dt}\left(\frac{\text{cc}}{\text{min}\cdot\text{g}}\right)$$
I suppose as long as you remember what the units are, given that the magnitude of $\rho^{-1}_{\text{brain}}$ is approximately $1.0$, we can drop it from the equation and write:
$$\text{CBF}(\tau^*)=\frac{V_{\tau^*}S}{\int_0^{\tau}\left[A(t)-V(t)\right]dt}\left(\frac{\text{cc}}{\text{min}\cdot\text{g}}\right) \quad (\dagger_3)$$
NOW, to answer the question of where does the $\frac{1}{100 \text{g}}$ come from...honestly, I feel like it is completely arbitrary and have no sense as to why this choice was made. As far as I can tell, Kety & Schmidt could have just as easily left the equation in its $(\dagger_3)$ form. However, for some reason that hopefully someone out there can figure out, they decided to multiply $(\dagger_3)$ by unity in the form of $\frac{100}{100}$, which then allowed them to rewrite $(\dagger_3)$ as:
\begin{align}\text{CBF}(\tau^*)&=\frac{100}{100}\times\frac{V_{\tau^*}S}{\int_0^{\tau}\left[A(t)-V(t)\right]dt}\left(\frac{\text{cc}}{\text{min}\cdot\text{g}}\right)\\&=\frac{100V_{\tau^*}S}{\int_0^{\tau}\left[A(t)-V(t)\right]dt}\left(\frac{\text{cc}}{\text{min}\cdot\text{100 g}}\right)\end{align}

I don't think any of this complication is necessary. There's a tradition in medicine to express in convenient units, where "typical" values are in the range of 10s to 100s, avoiding scales where values right of the decimal are important and values where values left of the decimal are meaningless.

@BryanKrause Well, it at least explains the dimensional mismatch stated in $(\dagger_1)$, so perhaps it is of use to someone. Though that tidbit about medical history is interesting. Thanks~

Oh, I see, I assumed your question was mainly about the "100" rather than the "grams". I think that one is pretty straightforward, too... Blood doesn't go places for fun, it feeds tissue. If you have different sized organs (say, in different individuals) they're going to have different blood flow not because of any sort of pathology or "interesting" difference but just because of the organ size difference. I wouldn't consider that a mismatch in dimensions any more than expressing, say, GDP per capita.

If you're wondering why mass instead of volume, blood is something you can pour into a measuring cylinder because it's liquid. Tissue isn't liquid and you can't easily measure its volume. You could use displacement but then you have to stick it in some other solution in a sufficient container. Easier to put on a scale.
